# gitignore - fatal: no files added

Tags: git

I have an issue with git, more precisely with gitignore.

I have created an empty folder
Initialized git

```
mkdir fold
cd fold
git init
```

Updated gitignore (as below)

```
 *.prjx
```

Committed gitignore

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "update gitignore"
```

Now I have several files (among them a .prjx) and folders in my root (fold) and I'd like to add all of them, but when I run

```
git add *
```

I get the message below

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
ftc.prjx
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

I don't want to add it, I simply want add all the other files and folders.
From my understanding .gitignore should handle exactly that so why I get the message above?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

you should run `git add .` rather than `git add *`

the `*` is interpreted by the shell and substituted with all file and folder in the current location.  obviously **ftc.prjx** is one of them and git is just warning that the file is in the ignorelist.

Comment: Great, and by the way "." means current folder, which would add everything in current folder.

Comment: My `git add .` still gives fatal

Comment: I bet you are not in the git folder.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to git rm --cached FILEFOLDER/*
To remove everything from a folder in my commit.