# Why doesn't "git add *" add files in the root directory?

Tags: macos, git, bash

**Edit:** Doing the steps below actually does reproduce the behavior. Yes, the file is named `stuff.txt` and it does not start with a `.` in the filename. When I do `echo *`, it does indeed print `stuff.txt`.

The command `git add *` is generally similar to `git add .` with one major exception: `git add *` will not add files in the root directory of the Git repository. It will not add new files (`??`) or modified existing files (`M`). Here are the steps necessary to reproduce:

```
mac$ mkdir myrepo
mac$ cd myrepo
mac$ git init
mac$ touch stuff.txt
mac$ git add *
fatal: no files added

mac$ git status -s
?? stuff.txt
# It looks like 'git add *' totally dropped the ball.

mac$ git add .
# Nothing prints. Success?
mac$ git status -s
A  stuff.txt
# Yes, success.
```

Any idea what the problem is? `git add *` works fine so long as the added or modified files are in a subdirectory, such as `myrepo/mydir/`. The problem only occurs for files at the top-level of the repository.

My setup:

Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks

Git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)

I got that version of Git by installing Apple Xcode.

Apple Terminal version 2.4 (326)

I should point out that I am purely asking out of curiosity. Using `git add .` is a 100% satisfactory work-around.

Comment: That is bizarre.  `*` is nothing to do with Git, it should be expanded by the shell.

Comment: Is the file actually called `stuff.txt` or does it its name start with a `.`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gitignore - fatal: no files added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084227/gitignore-fatal-no-files-added)

Comment: @Mat: The filename actually is `stuff.txt` with no `.` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

As implied by Mat's comment, `*` does not match anything that starts with a `.`. This is how the shell works (and nothing to do with git). You can test this by running `echo *` in your shell.

To match dotfiles, you'd have to use `.[!.]*`. (Test it using `echo .[!.]*`.) Using simply `.*` would also match `.` and `..`, which you don't want to do with `git add`.