# Git ignore directory using absolute path

Tags: linux, git, centos

Can absolute directory paths be used in .gitignore?  I put the following in /var/www/bidjunction/.gitignore, however, html was still tracked.  Why was it still tracked?

```
/var/www/bidjunction/html/
```

EDIT.  Somewhat off topic, but when I don't use an absolute path, nothing gets added.

```
[Michael@devserver bidjunction]$ cat .gitignore
html/
[Michael@devserver bidjunction]$ git add *
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
html
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
[Michael@devserver bidjunction]$
```

Comment: No. If path starts with `/` it's linked to root of git repo. So `/html` will ignore `html` file right beside the `.gitignore` but not `foo/html` in subfolder. [Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)

Comment: If '/html/' is to be ignored and .gitignore is present in '/var/www/bidjunction/' then shouldn't you just put 'html/*' in the .gitignore file?

Why are you entering:
'/var/www/bidjunction/html/' in the .gitignore file?

Comment: @alexeyten.  Ah, so it is always relative to the root of the git repo.  Guess that makes sense.  Couldn't really find this info at http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.

Comment: As for as my supplementary question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084227/gitignore-fatal-no-files-added provides an answer.  I believe Alexeyten's comment answers my primary question.

Comment: Well, I'm a bit wrong. It's relative to directory where `.gitignore` file is located. But it's rarely placed anywhere but root of git repo.
Here is quotes from docs: «These patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file.» and «A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname.»