# gitignore file doesn't ignore

Tags: github, gitignore, git-bash

I am new to git hub and I changed the .gitignore file with following line.

```
/src/main/webapp/app/app.constants.js
```

Then I build the project. But when I type git status in git bash still that app.constants.js file is displayed as a modified file. So where I get wrong?

Comment: And do I need to commit the gitignore file to git again before testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` only works for untracked files. As per [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status), git status only gives you the state of the working tree. The ignore will kick in when you commit the changes. So nothing unexpected there.

If you want to ignore status for ignored files you can do `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`

or you can clean the git cache: remove them from repository `git rm --cached <file>`

Answer (score 2):

A path starting with `/` is referring to its absolute path. You are likely trying to refer to a `src` subdirectory. Removing that leading `/` will do just that (refer to a relative directory).

Comment: Even the given path in `.gitignore` is present as "/path.." it is evaluated as relative, in the following manner: `<location of .gitignore file>/path...`

Comment: @dbi Have you got a source on that? I'll mark this answer as incorrect if you do.

Comment: `A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".` - [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).

Comment: @Alexey Ten [claims "/path" is evaluated as <root git repo>/path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196518/git-ignore-directory-using-absolute-path#comments-23196518) but I have no further knowing which of the two statements is correct and have no time to test it atm. If anybody can clarify this pls feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

These steps are working for me:

```
git rm --cached your_file_name_here
```

then simply add your file name in .gitignore like:

```
constants.js
```

Now you are good to go.
Thank you.