# Commiting all files ignores the ones in .gitignore?

Tags: git

I'm new at Git, so my question is:

Using

```
git commit -a -m "Message"
```

Will respect the .gitignore file? If I run

```
git add *
```

It says cannot do it since there are files changed and marked as being ignore.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084227/gitignore-fatal-no-files-added).

Comment: Thanks @GoBusto but not really the same... my question is about `git commit -a` not about `git add *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-a` flag in git-commit does not commit all the files in the working directory, simply the ones that *already exist* in the repository that have changed. This is different from `git add *` which uses the shell expansion of `*` to add all of the files to staging, even the ones that git has not managed before.

[(From git-commit man page)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)

> -a
>   --all
>
> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are
>   not affected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, I guess then that do: `git add specific/file.js` will add the file and the `git commit -a` wil add also that file, right?